# htaccess ignore part of path on development server

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write an .htaccess file for a development server that ignores part of the url.

IE. My development server is address is:

```
www.mydevserver.com/subdomains/site/home becomes
www.mydevserver.com/subdomains/site/index.php?page=home
```

and when on the live server:

```
www.myliveserver.com/home becomes
www.myliveserver.com/index.php?page=home
```

Therefore I would like a single script that simple ignores the `"/subdomains/site"` part of the URL

So far my script is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Why not just create a subdomain for your sites? Probably easier to control subdomains that specific directories.

Comment: What version of apache are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make first part optional by placing this rule in root .htaccess on development and live server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(subdomains/site/)?([a-z0-9]+)/?$ $1index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, this looks perfect. I'll be able to test it properly when the domains propagate.